# Weird kerning after apostrophe

Tags: fonts, kerning

I want to use the ETbb font in my document, but there is one thing in particular that is weird about it. The spacing after an apostrophe is sometimes too much. I do not know if this is intentional, but it does not look good in my opinion. The same is true with the default Computer Modern font.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ETbb}
\begin{document}
The Holy Qur'an
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the `a` to be right next to the apostrophe just like all of the other characters.

Comment: The kerning table of the font in question would appear to contain an incorrect value for the `'a` pair.

Comment: @Mico there is no kern, it's just a very wide `'` (or I suppose you could say it has an incorrect kern of 0)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. The reason I thought it was a kerning issue is that there‘s no problem with “don’t” and “can’t”, i.e., the `’t` glyph pair.

Comment: @Mico I think it's just the bar of t saves you visually, the actual space is the same, no kern in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The font has quite a wide `'` without changing the virtual font to add a kern pair for `'a` you could make `'` active and adjust the space, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\showoutput
\usepackage{ETbb}

\catcode`\'=\active
\AtBeginDocument{%
\catcode`\'=\active
\protected\def'{\futurelet\tmp\quotekern}%
}
\catcode`\'=12 


\def\quotekern{%
  \string'%
  \ifx\tmp a\kern-.1em\fi
  \ifx\tmp o\kern-.1em\fi
}
\begin{document}
The Holy Qur'an
\end{document}
```